# Is it better to store encryption keys, or to regenerate them every time?

Tags: encryption

I'm currently studying web security, purely on my own, to expand my skillset going forward in my career. I've been studying different encryption techniques, how best to employ them, etc.

The current situation I'm thinking about involves a multi-tenant database. Each schema in the database represents a different tenant. The data in each schema needs to be secured not only from outsiders, but from the other tenants as well.

To do this, I would use symmetric encryption, with a different key for each schema. But that's where my question comes in.

There are two ways to handle the keys, as I see it. One would be to have a secure location for storing the keys, like on a separate server. That would still require storing each and every key.

The second way would be re-generating the encryption key each time. The key would be a combination of a series of values related to the tenant that are stored in the database. Each time someone connects to the application, the key is re-generated by putting those values in the exact same order and hashing them.

I'm wondering if the second idea is overkill, or if it is a viable option. In general, though, I'm looking for guidance on how best to design database security policies.

Thank you.

Comment: If the key is generated from some known values (public), then this is not some key. On the other hand if these values are (partially) secret, then you're simply proposing to use a hash. Either way, the secret key and the secret values have the same function. Choose what is easiest, because none of the ways provide actual security, since the key/values have to be accessible to be used for decryption.

Comment: Use the database access control system to prevent users from accessing unauthorized schemas and objects. Encryption would be more appropriate for protecting the file system used by the whole database, or backups of the database, from offline attack.